# Swift2 Dictionary updateValue functions cause my app to crash when deployed but works perfectly in simulator, why?

Tags: ios, iphone

This section of code is suppose to update the "parentCategory" key in the dictionary to a different value based on the condition met. I have tested and run this code on the iPhone 5, 5s, 6 & 6s and also the iPad 2 Simulators and also Run on real device from Xcode which all works. However, when I code sign and export the .ipa file using the "Save for Enterprise Deployment" the app crashes at those lines. I am not sure exactly what causing but the error is very consistent. Please help me find a solution thanks.

```
  for video in item.ADVideos{

      var mutable_video: Dictionary<String,String> = video

      if(self.level == 0){
            if(item.Parent != nil){
                try mutable_video.updateValue(item.Parent!, forKey: "parentCategory")
             }
      }

      if(self.level == 1){
            if(item.parentCategory != nil){
                 try mutable_video.updateValue(item.parentCategory!, forKey: "parentCategory")
            }                 
      }

      if(self.level == 2){
           if(item.parentCategory != nil){
                try mutable_video.updateValue(item.parentCategory!, forKey: "parentCategory")
            }
      }
      allVideos += [mutable_video]
  }
```

Comment: Can you show details from the crash log?